# Weight lifting and muscle adhesions / knots

Tags: weightlifting, muscle

I've read that even someone doing yoga should also take massage / do foam rolling, in order to get out knots / adhesions.  Would someone with adhesions and tight muscles do fine with lifting and massage, or would stretching the muscles (e.g. with yoga) in addition to massage be more affective for someone with this problem?

Comment: There is no evidence that “adhesions” and “knots” exist. We havent seen any imaging or histology studies that detect those. Mostly, you are talking about muscle fatigue, and a lot of placebo effect of foam rolling/massage

Comment: sorry, here's link to read https://www.painscience.com/articles/trigger-point-doubts.php

Comment: @aaaaaa - spend 20 years sitting at a computer.  Then pick up foam rolling / massage.  I think you'll disagree with your past self.

Comment: (i spent 15 years sitting in front of computer) i am not saying pain isn't real or foam rolling didn't help. Just that mechanism is not based on anything but placebo effect. If foam rolling makes you train regularly and build extra muscle -- great. But you can't get depended on non-science based treatments.

Comment: @aaaaaa -interesting perspective, thanks.  When I am rolling or sitting on a lacrosse ball and feel that "hurts so good" spot, and keep the pressure on for 30-60 seconds until I feel the muscle relax, that is all in my head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stretching/yoga, and massage/foam rolling are two different things. Both are needed when you weight lifting. Both are good for motion range but deals with different problems.

With static stretching, you are addressing muscles, dynamic stretching deals with other structures. Yoga is static stretching, with some exercises done with body weight.

Adhesions usually mean that muscles are glued to a fascia, or fascias themselves. Dynamic stretching can help here, but a dedicated massage is much more efficient.

Next problem is when whole muscle pains. I had problems with wrist extensors, with pain from index finger to elbow. I was unable to do a handshake... After 2-3 months - smaller / bigger problems - I solved it with a lacrosse ball, and it took me 2-3 days to remove pain. So massage is for something like that. Since that, I'm a big fan of this method.

Runners love rolling after training since that helps with releasing tensions and allow them to relax, recover faster.

Doing static stretching after weight lifting is a bad idea since that stresses muscles twice. Foam rolling? For some that can be great, maybe not lacrosse ball, but foam should be great.

Hope it help.